# What does it mean for the Hessian of a convex function to be positive semidefinite?

Tags: convex-analysis, definition, convex-optimization, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

> **Given a twice-differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is convex iff $\nabla ^2 f(x) \succeq 0, \forall x \in \text{dom} f$.**

This is the definition given on these sets of notes https://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236b/lectures/functions.pdf

But I feel like something is missing in the definition...

What does it mean for $\nabla ^2 f(x) \succeq 0$?

**Does it mean:**

1. $y^T\nabla ^2 f(x)y \geq 0, \forall y \in  \text{dom} f$ or...
2. $y^T\nabla ^2 f(x)y \geq 0, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: The latter. $\nabla^2 f(x)$ is some matrix, and this is a condition on that matrix.

Comment: Answer 2. The matrix has to be positive semi-definite, and the definition for that applies $\forall y\in \mathcal(R)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the section "Generalized Inequalities" of [chapter 2](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjrtLCE-YLUAhVsAsAKHTjCC7cQFgg5MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Focw.mit.edu%2Fcourses%2Felectrical-engineering-and-computer-science%2F6-079-introduction-to-convex-optimization-fall-2009%2Flecture-notes%2FMIT6_079F09_lec02.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEGTu-gKxow-rCHAXHP5jkaCJwfaw&cad=rja).

$$
x \succeq y \iff x_i \ge y_i \quad (i \in \{ 1, \dotsc, n \}) \\
X \succeq Y \iff X - Y \text{ is positive semidefinite}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The Hessian of a function is a symmetric matrix, and so the usual definition of positive semidefiniteness applies. A symmetric matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is positive semidefinite provided that for all $y\in\mathbb{R^n}$ we have $y^TAy \geq 0$. Replacing $A$ with $\nabla ^2f(x)$ gives us your second definition.